# Find files based on content and sender, receiver and based on date range provided

Tags: unix, find

I would like to find files based on content and sender, receiver based date range provided

More details below:

Find files between date range (where folder names are the dates in the format `yyyyMMdd`) and file content. The folder structure is as below:

`/opt/test/work/yyyyMMdd/<senderName>/TransactionID/<receiverName>/<functionname>/<functionname>/<filename>`

`/opt/test/work/20131112/ABC/ffd88858-6104-449e-bd41-6cba4d6a255a/XYZ/PI/split/1_ANS213.dat`

Here is the command I used
find . -path "/*/ABC/*/XYZ/" -newerct 20131107 -not -newerct 20131111 -exec grep -iFl 'COMMENTS' {} + | sort | uniq | awk -F/ '{print }' | sort | uniq

The above command is giving the results but as I am using the -newerct if the folder 20131101 with modified timestamp to Nov 08 2013 I am also retrieving the other files part of this folder. The problem is I just need to search the files based on folder name where the name is actually a date.

Comment: find . -path "*/*/ABC/*/XYZ/*" -newerct 20131107 -not -newerct 20131111 -exec grep -iFl 'COMMENTS' {} + | sort | uniq | awk -F/ '{print }' | sort | uniq

Comment: The above command is giving the results but as I am using the -newerct if the folder 20131101 with modified timestamp to Nov 08 2013 I am also retrieving the other files part of this folder.  The problem is I just need to search the files based on folder name where the name is actually a date.

Comment: Please [edit] your question mentioning everything you already have and where the problem is. Thanks.